# How to install federated engine to my mariadb?

Tags: mysql, xampp, mariadb, federated-storage-engine

I know many of post have mention mariadb in xampp already include federated engine, but unfortunately the federated engine hasn't installed in my mariadb as you can see in the table below.

```
MariaDB [information_schema]> show engines;
+--------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| Engine             | Support | Comment                                                                                          | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
+--------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| CSV                | YES     | CSV storage engine                                                                               | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| InnoDB             | DEFAULT | Percona-XtraDB, Supports transactions, row-level locking, foreign keys and encryption for tables | YES          | YES  | YES        |
| MEMORY             | YES     | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables                                        | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MyISAM             | YES     | MyISAM storage engine                                                                            | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MRG_MyISAM         | YES     | Collection of identical MyISAM tables                                                            | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| Aria               | YES     | Crash-safe tables with MyISAM heritage                                                           | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA | YES     | Performance Schema                                                                               | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| SEQUENCE           | YES     | Generated tables filled with sequential values                                                   | YES          | NO   | YES        |
+--------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I also tried to follow the guide here and run this command `INSTALL PLUGIN federated SONAME 'ha_federatedx.so';` but got error `ERROR 1126 (HY000): Can't open shared library 'D:\xampp\mysql\lib\plugin\ha_federatedx.so.dll' (errno: 2, The specified module could not be found.` . Can anyone tell me how to install the federated engine without re-install xampp? My database version is `mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.10-MariaDB, for Win32 (AMD64)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this answer likely comes several years too late, but I was having the same problem this morning on a Windows development machine. I tried ...

```
INSTALL PLUGIN federated SONAME 'ha_federatedx.so';
```

... but it didn't work, and I received the same error as Deno did. After some searching, I found that *.so files are Linux shared library files, so I tried the following command ...

```
INSTALL PLUGIN federated SONAME 'ha_federatedx.dll';
```

... and it worked! The only caveat is I am working with an actual install of MariaDB, not the version installed in XAMPP, so the actual DLL file might need to be installed in XAMPP.

Hopefully, this will help someone else who is experiencing the same problem.

Comment: I forgot to update this question, I solved this problem by update my MariaDB.
The latest MariaDB have included the plugin in the folder.